# replace all characters, before a specific character , mysql query

Tags: mysql, replace

Edit:
i would like to replace all characters, before a specific character , using mysql query.
The location of the specific character is not always the same.

The select function is giving me all the characters before

```
SELECT LEFT(description_short,LOCATE('<hr',description_short) as myresult
```

How i can combine it with the replace , so i can replace all those characters?

Something like that...

```
UPDATE  ps_product_lang , SELECT LEFT(description_short,LOCATE('<hr ',description_short) as myresult 
SET `description_short`= replace(`description_short`,myresult,'mynewtext')
```

---

I got it finally...
i dont know if it is the elegant way , but it works for me.

UPDATE `my_table`,(SELECT @replacetext := ((SELECT LEFT(`description`, LOCATE("description)-1)  from my_table  where my_table.id_product=72 and my_table.id_lang=4 ))) as somealias
SET `description`= replace(`description`,@replacetext,"mynewtextbefore characters")
WHERE (`id_product`='72') 
AND (`id_shop`='1') 
AND (`id_lang`='4')

The above find and replace with "mynewtextbefore characters" all the characters before 
"

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like that?

```
SELECT CONCAT('mynewtext',
              SUBSTRING(description_short, -LOCATE('<hr', description_short)-3)
       );
```

See http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/69c43/3

Comment: I cannot make it work , may be you can provide the complete code?

Comment: @user2650912 If you read carefully my answer, you will see I provide a sqlfiddle as a live example...